# iPhone 3G not automatically retrieving emails at the main Email Accounts page since version 3

Tags: iphone, email

Since upgrading the iPhone 3G software to version 3 the Email client no longer automatically updates my emails when entering the mail app on the first "Accounts" page.

Even pressing the "Refresh" button (ie. the little circular arrow at bottom left) doesn't force a connection.

This used to work on the previous o/s version.

It only now works if I go into the Inbox of a specfic mail account.

Anybody any ideas why this has stopped working ?

Comment: This seems to be fixed now after installing the latest version of the iTunes software (v9) and the iPhone O/S (v3.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now after installing the latest version of the iTunes software (v9) and the iPhone O/S (v3.1).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting all accounts and recreating them? That would reset all the settings back to default, or should.

Comment: If I delete them from the iPhone and then re-sync should it then copy them back automacially ?

Comment: I wouldn't resync before then. Set up the accounts first.

Answer (score 1):

You might try going to Settings > General > Reset > "Reset Network Settings". I have had that fix this problem before, though your luck may vary. 
Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it set to do a Fetch every so often for your mail account?

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Fetch New Data > Under Fetch, make sure either Every 15 Minutes or Every 30 Minutes is checked off.